# After reinstalling Android Studio have an error while build project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:158)
> Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:116)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:34)
> at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)

what may be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and rebuild your project doing this:

```
   `Build > Clean Project`  
   `Build > Rebuild Project`
```

If this will not work, try invalidate cache:

```
   `File > Invalidate cache...`
```

[image]